# Hibernate create a list of type integer from 2 tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, orm

I'm trying to create a class that has a list of integers

```
@Table(name = "kidding")
@SecondaryTable(name = "kids_list")
public class Kidding {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "kiddingID")
    private long kiddingID;

    @Column(name = "doeID")
    private int doeID;

    @Column(name = "buckID")
    private int buckID;

    @Column(name = "fertilityDate")
    private Date fertilityDate;

    @Column(name = "kiddingDate")
    private Date kiddingDate;


    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="kids_list", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="kiddingID"))
    @Column(name = "kidID")
    private List<Integer> kidIDs;

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;

    @Column(name = "ownerID")
    private long ownerID;
```

I have these two tables: Kidding and Kids_list

the kidding has a primary key kiddingID and the kids_list has a foreign key connected to the primary key of kidding

Table Kidding:

| kiddingID (PK) | doeID | BuckID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 3 | 5 | 8 |
| 4 | 7 | 9 |

Table kids_list:

| kiddingID (FK) | kidID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |

In the end, I want to fill my list of integers in the object kidding like this :

```
When I get kidding 1:
List<Integer> kidsID {1,2,3}

When I get kidding 2:
List<Integer> kidsID {4,8}

When I get kidding 3:
List<Integer> kidsID {7,9}

When I get kidding 4:
List<Integer> kidsID {5,6}
```

is there a way to do this with hibernate?

ATM I'm only getting the kid id if there is 1 kid from the kidding but if there is 2 I get this error :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 2, for class: com.GoatPool.goatpool.model.Kidding
```

If the question or something else is unclear please say so. I would like to explain it in more detail if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@SecondaryTable`. Hibernate ORM already knows that there is a secondary table because of the mapping with `@ElementCollection`.

`@SecondaryTable` is used if you have the property of a single entity spread in multiple tables. This is not your case because what you are mapping in the other table is an association.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I can't believe this solved it! I'm really happy. I'm really new to the ORM stuff and spent a lot of time on this problem!